# Gmail API : pull emails but not hangouts

Tags: php, api, gmail, pull, google-hangouts

I am using the Google APIs Gmail in PHP to pull emails from my inbox and display them in my webapp. My problem is : Hangouts are pulled as well. I would like to pull only emails. I wanted to filter them by Labels but apparently Hangouts are labelled "INBOX" as well.

What can I do to pull only emails and avoid Hangouts ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the "q" parameter when listing the user's messages and specify "!in:chats" along with any other filters you may need.

Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).